# How to write this complex SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image]

[image]

I need to find the names of aircraft such that **all pilots** certified to operate them earn more than 60000.

Query I wrote:

```
select aname 
from employee join certified
on employee.eid=certified.eid
join aircraft
on certified.aid=aircraft.aid
where salary>60000;
```

But it returns aname if there is any pilot with more than 60000 salary,difficult part is that i need to find if all pilots earn more than 60000 only then the aname is displayed.

Comment: You can use `WHERE .. IN ALL (subquery)`. Check the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

Comment: Sorry, corrected it @Pudding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just look for the opposite case - that **no** pilots earn less than 60,000:

```
SELECT
    aname
FROM
    Aircraft A
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Certified C
        INNER JOIN Employee E ON
            E.eid = C.eid AND
            E.salary < 60000
        WHERE C.aid = A.aid
    )
```

Comment: I've gotten faster at typing ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, its really helpful .it proves  that there are  still lots of things that google can't tell you but people can. Thank you again @TomH

Comment: One more question , how do i learn to figure out these kind of problems by myself, any text you can recommend. @TomH

Comment: Just a matter of getting your brain used to approaching problems in new ways. I do a lot of puzzle books. :)  Also, it's useful to know logical equivalencies and inverses (X AND Y vs. NOT (NOT X OR NOT Y) for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT aname FROM Aircraft where NOT EXISTS (SELECT eid FROM Employee AS e INNER JOIN Certified AS c ON c.eid=e.eid WHERE salary<60000 AND aid=Aircraft.aid)
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT
    aname
FROM
    Aircraft A
WHERE
     EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Certified C
        INNER JOIN Employee E ON
            E.eid = C.eid AND
            E.salary > 60000
        WHERE C.aid = A.aid
    )

Comment: In @Tom H 's query , take all  aircraft aname which has no employee